# How can we not know the $s$-measure of the Sierpiński triangle?

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, fractals

I'm preparing a presentation that would enable high-school level students to grasp that the (self-similarity) dimension of an object needs not be an integer. The first example we look at is the Sierpiński triangle and with some effort we learn that its dimension is $$s := \log(3)/\log(2) \approx 1.585.$$ After this I thought that it would be nice to mention what the actual Hausdorff $s$-measure of the triangle is, but all I found was measure estimates for [a certain class of Sierpiński carpets](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X04008868) and some 
[estimates of the Sierpiński triangle](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243540711_Estimate_of_the_hausdorff_measure_of_the_sierpinski_triangle).

I am literally shocked to learn that we apparently do not know the exact value of Hausdorff $s$-measure of the Sierpiński triangle! Especially since it's such a concrete and symmetric object. To comply to the idea of this site hosting questions instead of rants, I formulate my bafflement as follows:

> Why is the $s$-measure of the Sierpiński triangle and other self-similar fractals so hard to calculate?

Are we missing a link to some complicated machinery or is the problem connected to some deep problem that one would expect to remain unsolved?

Comment: That's an interesting question! But I want to add that I would not know what to make of the fact that some specific set would have $0.7664$-dimenaional measure $1$. I suspect that the same is true for others and this may explain that some people would not put too much effort in such calculations.

Comment: I don't know this subject at all, but is there any reason to expect the answer to be a [closed-form number](http://timothychow.net/closedform.pdf)? If the answer is not a closed-form number, what would one mean by "knowing the exact value"?

Comment: @TimothyChow One could ask for a relatively fast algorithm for computing the digits of the number. Based on the reference above, it looks like it's not even known to one significant digit, so "closed-form" isn't really the issue..

Comment: @verret : Granted. I was reacting to the sentence, "I am literally shocked to learn that we apparently do not know the exact value."

Comment: Do you know exactly how many disks of radius 1 it would take to cover a disc of radius 1000000? I think this is the flavour of the question you’re asking. (Yes I know with Hausdorff dimension you’re allowed to have sets of different diameters, but morally...)

Comment: @TimothyChow admittedly an *exact* value might be too much to hope for, but I would be satisfied even with a complicated integral/series/limit or something that could be used at least in theory to approximate it to any given precision like verret said.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Maybe the thing is not to be confused why we can't measure the Sierpinski triangle but why we can measure anything at all. (I recall once calculating the Lebesgue measure of a unit square that was rotated by 45 degrees starting from the definition and it was not easy at all.)

But on the other hand we have been able to calculate various measures of various shapes, and the Sierpinski Triangle is so very symmetric that I'm aching to just say that there is some clever trick to get good approximations.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the bounds in terms of $a_n$ due to Jia mentioned in the article you link are exactly what you hope for - a method that can be used to approximate it for any given precision, at least in theory.  That's of course compatible with less than 1 digit being known in practice.

Comment: @WillSawin Maybe I'm running to my personal subjective limit on what counts as a solution. Indeed, the measure is the limit of the sequence $(a_n)$ in the paper, but I seem to instinctively reject the solution as a satisfactory answer.  Maybe it's due to the fact that the values of the sequence are so hard to calculate or even approximate that getting new estimates is worth publishing in a peer-reviewed journal? In the end the sad fact is that the amount of interesting things is much larger than the number of interesting things with natural (for me) descriptions.

Comment: There may be some hope to make the computations easier by combining the methods of this paper with other methods (e.g. SAT solvers), but I don't know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any exact results for Hausdorff Measure?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/204206/are-there-any-exact-results-for-hausdorff-measure)

Answer (score 7):

The latest I could find is

*Móra, Péter*, [**Estimate of the Hausdorff measure of the Sierpinski triangle**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1142/S0218348X09004296), Fractals 17, No. 2, 137-148 (2009). [ZBL1178.28007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1178.28007).

where the best values are given as
$$
0.77 \le \mathscr{H}^s(\Lambda) \le 0.81794 .
$$
He also proves an upper estimate $\mathscr{H}^s(\Lambda) \le 0.819161232881177$ of which he says "everybody can check it easily".

He also explains why this is harder and more technical than the reasons found in the comments here; for instance, the obvious upper bound gives only $\mathscr{H}^s(\Lambda) \le 1$.

Comment: That's actually the paper behind the second links in the question.

Comment: He says it is not so easy to check the best published upper bound because it was published in Chinese.

Comment: Paywall-free version of the papers: [lower bound](http://math.bme.hu/~morap/sierpinski.pdf), [upper bound](https://www.ixueshu.com/document/48dd17d97a1119d5318947a18e7f9386.html).