# How do sets with unit fractional Hausdorff measure of dimension $>1$ look like?

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, fractals, hausdorff-dimension, hausdorff-measure

Triggered by the recent question [How can we not know the measure of the Sierpiński triangle?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/344304/9652) I would like to ask:

> Let $s>1$ and $s$ not be an integer. How to construct a set $A$ with $\mathfrak{H}^s(A) = 1$, i.e. an $s$-dimensional set with $s$-dimensional Hausdorff measure $1$? Is there a set which in some sense "as simple as possible"?

For $0<s<1$ this is not so difficult, since covering with disjoint intervals
makes the respective terms as large as possible, but I do not see how a similar argument can be made in higher dimensions.

Phrased differently: What should "the unit cube in $d$-dimensions" be for non-integer $d>1$.

Comment: an option would be to construct a set $A$ with $0<H^s(A)<\infty$ and then [scale](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3326723/scaling-property-proof-of-hausdorff-measure) to make the measure equal 1.

Comment: @skeeve Sure, that's why I aaked about measure 1 in the first place. The thing is: You need to know the measure! (From the linked question it seems like we do not know any of these...)

Answer (score 2):

Let $s>1$ be aby number.
The unit interval $[0,1]$ with the metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|^{1/s}$ has poisitive and finite $s$-dimensional Hausdorff measure. While, it is an abstract metric space, it can be embedded in a bi-Lipschitz way into a Euclidean space by Assouad's theorem and the embedded set will have positive and finite $s$-dimensional Hausdorff measure.

We say that a metric space $(X,d)$ is *doubling* if there is $M$ such that every ball $B$ in $X$ can be covered by at most $M$ balls with half the radius of $B$.

**Theorem (Assouad).**
*Let $(X,d)$ be a doubling metric space. Then for any $\alpha\in (0,1)$, there is $N$ and a bi-Lipschitz embedding $\Phi:(X,d^\alpha)\to\mathbb{R}^N$, i.e. a mapping such that
$$
C_1d(x,y)^\alpha\leq |\Phi(x)-\Phi(y)|\leq C_2d(x,y)^\alpha
$$
for some $C_1,C_2>0$ and all $x,y\in X$.*

You simply apply the result to $X=[0,1]$ and $\alpha=1/s$. There is a quite extensive literature on the Assouad theorem. You can find the proof in the book by Heinonen.

*Heinonen, Juha*, [**Lectures on analysis on metric spaces**](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4613-0131-8), Universitext. New York, NY: Springer (2001). [ZBL0985.46008](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0985.46008).

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting, and I did not know this theorem before. However, it is not really what I was looking for, as neither the embedding is concrete (not even $N$ seems to be clear…) nor do I see what the value of the measure of $\Phi(X)$ is.

Comment: @Dirk I am not sure what you are looking for. There are several different constructions and I will mention some more when I have time. Is it just out of curiosity or you need it   for some specific problem? Knowing that I could try to tailor he example to your needs.

Comment: Actually, my question was just out of curiosity, so you don't need to put in a lot of effort…